# Harry Potter fanfic called "What Comes After", where Harry is abused and Snape and Malfoy help him

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I’m looking for this fanfiction called "What Comes After", which was posted on Archive of Our Own. Sadly I don’t remember the author. It was some kind of storyline where Harry is/was abused. Severus Snape and Draco Malfoy were involved in an at least friendly way. The first upload was at least 2 years old.

I can’t find the story anywhere. Maybe the name changed? Or it was deleted from AO3? Maybe it’s now on another site?

Can anyone find the story I'm looking for, and a place where I can read it?

Comment: This one? It was started in 2011. https://www.fanfiction.net/s/7104654/1/A-New-Place-To-Stay

Answer (score -1):

Is this it - [What comes After](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/6879370/1/What-Comes-After)

Its description reads - "After the Last Battle, Harry Potter had only one question: now what? And Hermione Granger seems to be the only one with a satisfying answer."

I found it by searching "what comes after harry potter fanfic" on google

The only problem is it was posted on April 5, 2011, 11 years ago and as pointed out in the comments, doesnt involve Harry being abused or living with Snape and Malfoy

Comment: This doesn't seem to match any of the details of the story they're looking for, such as Harry being abused, or living with Snape and Draco.

Comment: Sadly this isn’t the story.